# Uploading images to iphone withou resizing

Tags: iphone

I want to create application that does something with users images that he can import from his computer. Problem is I need those images in original size. When I try to copy them through iTunes sync, they are resized to 640x480 or something and this is unacceptable for me :( Is there some setting in iTunes or iPhone that I missed that will allow me to sync images without resize?

Is there any other way how user can copy image from PC or mac to iPhone without iTunes? I want this to be as convenient as possible for user, ideally without forcing him to download and install any new software

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on what your resources are. You could have them upload them to your server and you could download them to the iPhone.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but it just doesn't seem simple enough for average user. Also, there will be probably web application that will do same thing as my iphone app, so it is kinda pointless to upload it somewhere and then download it back to iphone when user could use web app directly.

What do you mean by my resources?